# Explicit bijection between circles mod $p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be a prime and $a, b \in \{1,\ldots,p-1\}$. One can show that the number of pairs $(x,y)$ with $x^2 + y^2 \equiv a \pmod p$ is equal to the number of pairs $(u,v)$ with $u^2 + v^2 \equiv b \pmod p$. Can this be done with an explicit bijection between the pairs? In case $ab^{-1} = z^2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $(x,y) \leftrightarrow (xz, yz)$ works, but what if $ab$ is not a square modulo $p$ - is there still a nice direct way to do it?

Comment: The statement is wrong: consider $p = 3, a = 0, b = 1$.

Comment: @WhatsUp oops I wanted to write a, b to be nonzero thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$G=\{ \pmatrix{x&y\\-y&x}\in M_2(\Bbb{F}_p), x^2+y^2\ne 0\}$$ is a group.
Then  $$\det :G\to \Bbb{F}_p^\times$$ is surjective because (for $p$ odd) both $\{ x^2,x\in \Bbb{F}_p\},\{a- y^2,y\in \Bbb{F}_p\}$ contain $\frac{p+1}2$ elements

For each $M_{a/b}\in G$ such that $\det(M_{a/b})=a/b$ there is a bijection $$\det{}^{-1}(a)= M_{a/b} \det{}^{-1}(b)$$

Comment: Awesome! To rephrase it in more elementary terms: by Pigeonhole there exist $u_0$ and $v_0$ such that $u_0^2 + v_0^2 \equiv ba^{-1}$. Then $(x,y) \to (xu_0 - yv_0, xv_0 + yu_0)$ works essentially since $(xu_0 - yv_0)^2 + (xv_0 + yu_0)^2 \equiv (x^2+y^2)(u_0^2+v_0^2) \equiv b$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way provided $p\equiv1\pmod4$, in which case $-1$ is a square modulo $p$, and we can consider the equation $u^2-v^2\equiv b\pmod p$ instead. Suppose $x^2-y^2\equiv a\pmod p$ and $ab\not\equiv0\pmod p$. Let
$$u=\frac{(x+y)+(x-y)a^{-1}b}2,\qquad v=\frac{(x+y)-(x-y)a^{-1}b}2,$$
where $a^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $a$ modulo $p$ in $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$.
Then
$$u^2-v^2=(x+y)(x-y)a^{-1}b\equiv b\pmod p.$$
The inverse $(u,v)\mapsto(x,y)$ is obvious.